# My screen dims unexpectedly

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro, osx-lion, backlight

Let's say I'm watching a movie and all of a sudden my MacBook Pro 13 inch screen will dim. It's not getting ready to go to sleep. Some of the screen lights up and then the whole screen goes black. The backlight turned off. What should I do? i bought it on june 22 2011

Comment: What are your settings in *System Preferences > Energy Saver*? Please add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be inadvertently covering the ambient light sensor (i'm not even sure where they're located any more), which is causing the screen to dim because it thinks the room has gotten darker.

Also, depending on what software you're using, it may not disable the 'dim screen' feature.  You might check the preferences of it to see if there's an option somewhere for that.

Comment: The sensor is right next to the iSight-camera (cover it to verify).

Answer (score 1):

If your MacBook Pro is old enough to have a CCFL (fluorescent) backlight as opposed to modern LED backlights, then it could be that your CCFL lamp or the inverter board is failing. Check with AppleCare.

Comment: i just bought it on june 22 2011